# Query regarding the "width" option for format specifiers in python?

Tags: python

Here's an example of a format specifier in Python:

```
"%10.6f"
```

So the first number 10 corresponds to the width of the entry and the second number corresponds to the number of decimal places the entry can have.

My question is, what exactly is the purpose of changing the width of the entry? I assume this is entirely a cosmetic option to make the formatting of several numbers look neater - equivalent to typing a bunch of numbers in word and aligning them to the right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying the width of the field allows you to *pad* the field. The default is to pad out the field to the minimal width with spaces on the left:

```
>>> '%10.6f' % 1.234
'  1.234000'
>>> '%20.6f' % 1.234
'            1.234000'
```

but you can also pad the field with zeros:

```
>>> '%010.6f' % 1.234
'001.234000'
>>> '%020.6f' % 1.234
'0000000000001.234000'
```

or left-adjust with spaces:

```
>>> '%-10.6f' % 1.234
'1.234000  '
>>> '%-20.6f' % 1.234
'1.234000            '
```

You could use this to align your values in columns in a larger table, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The main way that I have used this to print tables.

```
data = [[1, 1, 1,], [11, 11, 11,], [111, 111, 111]]
for row in data:
    for col in row:
        print('%10.1f' % col, end='')
    print()

Output -->
   1.0       1.0       1.0       1.0
  11.0      11.0      11.0      11.0
 111.0     111.0     111.0     111.0
```

It is important to note that it does actually create a string that includes those spaces, so its uses, while probably cosmetic, are not strictly cosmetic.